# How to join JSON to table (SQL Server)

Tags: json, sql-server, inner-join, sql-server-json

I am trying to join an array of JSON to a table in SQL Server (in hopes of avoiding using TVP).

**Table Data**

```
| item_id   | qty |
|-----------|-----|
| dur 20001 | 1   |
| dur 93677 | 1   |
```

**SQL**

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '[{
  "order":{
    "address":{
      "addLine": "123 ABC Ln.",
      "citySt": "Los Angeles, CA"'
    },
  "items":[
    "line":{
      "id":"ABC 12345",
      "qty":"1"
  }]}, {
  "order":{
    "address":{
      "addLine": "987 Def Ln.",
      "citySt": "Los Angeles, CA"
    },
  "items":[
    "line":{
      "id":"DEF 12345",
      "qty":"1"
  }]}
]'


select * 
from someTable st
inner join @json 
on vt.item_id in (select json_value(@json,'$.items[0].line.id') 
  from openjson(@json,'$.items[0]'))
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> Must declare the table variable "@json".

How can I join to `someTable` with JSON in this form?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correctly formatted json string? I'm trying to parse it on my machine and it just throws an error

Comment: Hm... possibly. `[{
  "order":{
    "address":{
      "shipToAddLine":null,
      "shipToCityStZip":null
    },
  "items":[
    {"line":{
      "idItem":"DUR 82674",
      "qty":"1"
  }}]}}, {
  "order":{
    "address":{
      "shipToAddLine":null,
      "shipToCityStZip":null
    },
  "items":[
    {"line":{
      "idItem":"DUR 82674",
      "qty":"1"
  }}]}}
]`

Comment: @Matthew I added an additional `sql-server-json` tag to the question. If you think, that this is not appropriate, please remove the tag. Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov That's great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you getting error 'Must declare the table variable "@json"', then you need to run the entire peace of code in one batch.
Before you can join json string to the table, you need to parse it. 
Below is the example of how to do it. I did it on my machine and I'm getting values.

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) 
set @json = 
'[{ 
"order":{ 
    "address":{ 
        "shipToAddLine":null, 
        "shipToCityStZip":null 
    }, 
    "items":[ 
        {"line":{ 
            "idItem":"DUR 82674", 
            "qty":"1" 
    }}]}}, { 
"order":{ 
    "address":{ 
        "shipToAddLine":null, 
        "shipToCityStZip":null 
    }, 
    "items":[ 
        {"line":{ 
        "idItem":"DUR 82674", 
        "qty":"1" 
}}]}} 
]'



select *
from someTable st join openjson(@json)
with(
itemId varchar(50) '$.order.items[0].line.idItem'
) as js
on st.itemid = js.itemID
```

Comment: Your first comment is noted, and has been corrective.

Comment: However, I'm getting `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.` with the second example, and also `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'`

Comment: @Matthew I'm sorry I had a typo. try to run it again. I edited the second 'from' and put 'join' instead.

Comment: Hm. It looks good, but is not returning any records. When I select directly from `someTable` with each `itemId` I get two records...

Comment: Can you provide some sample data from 'someTable' that will be related to json string

Comment: Yes, just added some.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200192/discussion-between-kelevra-and-matthew).

Comment: BOOM. GOLDEN.
Thank you @kelevra!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider the fact, that the `items` part of the input `JSON` is an array of `JSON` objects, so it's necessary to use additional `CROSS APPLY` operator to parse this `JSON` array:

Table and JSON:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   idItem varchar(10),
   qty int
)
INSERT INTO #Data 
   (idItem, qty)
VALUES   
   ('DUR 20001', 1),
   ('DUR 93677', 1),
   ('DUR 82674', 1)

DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[{ 
  "order": { 
    "address":{ 
        "shipToAddLine": null, 
        "shipToCityStZip": "ZipCode"
    }, 
    "items":[ 
        {"line":{ 
            "idItem":"DUR 82674", 
            "qty":"1" 
        }},
        {"line":{ 
            "idItem":"DUR 82674", 
            "qty":"1" 
            }}
    ]
  }}, { 
  "order":{ 
    "address":{ 
        "shipToAddLine": null, 
        "shipToCityStZip": "ZipCode" 
    }, 
    "items":[ 
        {"line":{ 
        "idItem":"DUR 82674", 
        "qty":"1" 
        }}
    ]
  }} 
]'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Data d
JOIN (
   SELECT 
      i.shipToAddLine,
      i.shipToCityStZip,
      j.idItem,
      j.qty
   FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
      shipToAddLine varchar(100) '$.order.address.shipToAddLine',
      shipToCityStZip varchar(100) '$.order.address.shipToCityStZip',
      items nvarchar(max) '$.order.items' AS JSON
   ) i
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(i.items) WITH (
      idItem varchar(10) '$.line.idItem',
      qty int '$.line.qty'
   ) j
) json ON d.idItem = json.idItem
```

Result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
idItem      qty    shipToAddLine    shipToCityStZip idItem      qty
-------------------------------------------------------------------
DUR 82674   1                       ZipCode         DUR 82674   1
DUR 82674   1                       ZipCode         DUR 82674   1
DUR 82674   1                       ZipCode         DUR 82674   1
```