# SQL Server 2019 and path for JSON_QUERY

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to extract data from Json stored in a column and save as relational data in tables. The Json represents submissions of a pre-start checklist by a driver.

The input data is stored in a table, with `SubmitId` being the primary key and `FormDetails` holding the json. I get the unprocessed submissions and attempt to process them. To make life easier, I add the submitId key to the unprocessed json with `JSON_MODIFY`.

Doing it with a WHILE loop because that's how my brain works. I get the json into a variable, and then run some `OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json, <path>))` on it

I can successfully extract the `FormSubmission` and the `SectionSubmission` details.

```
SELECT 
    DeviceId, FormId, Id, IsPassed, SubmitDate, SubmitId, UserId
FROM
    OPENJSON(@json) 
    WITH (
        SubmitId int '$.submitId',
        DeviceId varchar(500) '$.deviceId',
        FormId int '$.formId',
        Id int '$.id',
        IsPassed bit '$.isPassed',
        SubmitDate datetime '$.submitDate',
        --SubmittedSections varchar(max) '$.submittedSections',
        UserId int '$.userId'
        ) AS form

SELECT 
    @SubmitId AS SubmitId,
    SectionId,
    FormId,
    UserId,
    CASE 
        WHEN UPPER(SectionDisplayed) = 'TRUE' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS SectionDisplayed,
    SectionPass,
    SectionTotal
FROM 
    OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.submittedSections')) 
    WITH (
        --Answers varchar(max) '$.answers',
        FormId int '$.formId',
        Id int '$.id',
        SectionDisplayed varchar(5) '$.sectionDisplayed',
        SectionId int '$.sectionId',
        SectionPass int '$.sectionPass',
        SectionTotal int '$.sectionTotal',
        UserId int '$.userId'
    ) AS section
```

However, when trying the same for the answers, I get a header row with the column names, and no data

```sql
    SELECT
        @SubmitId as SubmitId,
        SectionId,
        QuestionId,
        CASE 
            WHEN UPPER(AnswerBoolean) = 'TRUE' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END as AnswerBoolean,
        Comment,
        FailType,
        UserId
    FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.submittedSections.answers')) 
    WITH (
        SectionId int '$.sectionId',
        QuestionId int '$.questionId',
        AnswerBoolean varchar(5) '$.answerBoolean',
        Comment varchar(max) '$.comment',
        FailType int '$.failType',
        UserId int '$.userId'
        --Id int '$.id', -- Always 0
    ) 
    as answer
```

When removing the schema stuff to see what is coming back

```sql
    SELECT
        @SubmitId as SubmitId,
        *
    FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.submittedSections.answers')) 
    as answer
```

I get the following results header with no data (not even the SubmitId)

| SubmitId | key | value | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I initially tried to do this using `CROSS APPLY` following the example in [question 58172902](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58172902/how-to-join-json-to-table-sql-server) but couldn't get it going, hence the steps approach.

**Actual Question**

I'm assuming I've made a mistake in the path for my `JSON_QUERY`. What should it be? Or what else is wrong?

I'm expecting results that are a table of submitted answers.

The json, prettified:

```json
    {
        "deviceId": "8da23f818430c282",
        "formId": 2,
        "id": 0,
        "isPassed": true,
        "submitDate": "2023-03-27T15:40:59",
        "submittedSections": [
            {
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 1,
                        "sectionId": 1,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 2,
                        "sectionId": 1,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 3,
                        "sectionId": 1,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 4,
                        "sectionId": 1,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 5,
                        "sectionId": 1,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 6,
                        "sectionId": 1,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 7,
                        "sectionId": 1,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 8,
                        "sectionId": 1,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 9,
                        "sectionId": 1,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 10,
                        "sectionId": 1,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 11,
                        "sectionId": 1,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 12,
                        "sectionId": 1,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 13,
                        "sectionId": 1,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 14,
                        "sectionId": 1,
                        "userId": 0
                    }
                ],
                "formId": 2,
                "id": 0,
                "sectionDisplayed": true,
                "sectionId": 1,
                "sectionPass": 14,
                "sectionTotal": 14,
                "userId": 0
            },
            {
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 1,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 1,
                        "sectionId": 2,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 1,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 2,
                        "sectionId": 2,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 1,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 3,
                        "sectionId": 2,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 1,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 4,
                        "sectionId": 2,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 1,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 5,
                        "sectionId": 2,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 2,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 6,
                        "sectionId": 2,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 1,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 7,
                        "sectionId": 2,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 1,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 8,
                        "sectionId": 2,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 1,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 9,
                        "sectionId": 2,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 1,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 10,
                        "sectionId": 2,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 1,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 11,
                        "sectionId": 2,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 1,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 12,
                        "sectionId": 2,
                        "userId": 0
                    }
                ],
                "formId": 2,
                "id": 0,
                "sectionDisplayed": true,
                "sectionId": 2,
                "sectionPass": 12,
                "sectionTotal": 12,
                "userId": 0
            },
            {
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 1,
                        "sectionId": 3,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 2,
                        "sectionId": 3,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 3,
                        "sectionId": 3,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 4,
                        "sectionId": 3,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 5,
                        "sectionId": 3,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 6,
                        "sectionId": 3,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 7,
                        "sectionId": 3,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 8,
                        "sectionId": 3,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 9,
                        "sectionId": 3,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 0,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 10,
                        "sectionId": 3,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 1,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 11,
                        "sectionId": 3,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 1,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 12,
                        "sectionId": 3,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 1,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 13,
                        "sectionId": 3,
                        "userId": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answerBoolean": true,
                        "comment": "",
                        "failType": 1,
                        "id": 0,
                        "questionId": 14,
                        "sectionId": 3,
                        "userId": 0
                    }
                ],
                "formId": 2,
                "id": 0,
                "sectionDisplayed": true,
                "sectionId": 3,
                "sectionPass": 14,
                "sectionTotal": 14,
                "userId": 0
            }
        ],
        "userId": 0
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `JSON_QUERY` as `OPENJSON` can accept a path. But you can only break out the lowest-level array, you cannot break out multiple array levels this way, unless you use a fixed index such as `$.submittedSections[0].answers`.

So just use `CROSS APPLY` to feed one `OPENJSON` into the next. Note that you don't need `WHILE` loops either, you can `APPLY` the original `OPENJSON` directly from the main table.

Also you can use `bit` as a data type and it will convert from `true` or `false`.

```sql
SELECT
  d.SubmitId,
  SectionId,
  QuestionId,
  AnswerBoolean,
  Comment,
  FailType,
  UserId
FROM YourData d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.json, '$.submittedSections')
  WITH (
    answers nvarchar(max) AS JSON
  ) AS sections
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(sections.answers)
    WITH (
        SectionId int '$.sectionId',
        QuestionId int '$.questionId',
        AnswerBoolean bit '$.answerBoolean',
        Comment varchar(max) '$.comment',
        FailType int '$.failType',
        UserId int '$.userId'
        --Id int '$.id', -- Always 0
    ) 
    as answer;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/_wMxhbeU)

You could also add more `OPENJSON` calls if you want details from higher levels.

Comment: Accepted as this felt a bit more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I have almost done it. Just need to add the `answers` array as JSON in your first OPENJSON statement. Then perform the cross apply:

```
DECLARE @SubmitId INT = 1

SELECT 
    @SubmitId AS SubmitId,
    section.SectionId,
    section.FormId,
    section.UserId,
    CASE 
        WHEN UPPER(section.SectionDisplayed) = 'TRUE' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS SectionDisplayed,
    section.SectionPass,
    section.SectionTotal,
    answers_data.*
FROM 
    OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.submittedSections')) 
    WITH (
        --Answers varchar(max) '$.answers',
        FormId int '$.formId',
        Id int '$.id',
        SectionDisplayed varchar(5) '$.sectionDisplayed',
        SectionId int '$.sectionId',
        SectionPass int '$.sectionPass',
        SectionTotal int '$.sectionTotal',
        UserId int '$.userId',
        answers nvarchar(MAX) '$.answers' AS JSON
    ) AS section
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(section.answers)
WITH (
        AnswerBoolean varchar(5) '$.answerBoolean',
        Comment varchar(max) '$.comment',
        questionID INT '$.questionId',
        FailType int '$.failType',
        UserId int '$.userId'
        --Id int '$.id', -- Always 0
    ) answers_data
```

[image]

Comment: So frustrating! Why doesn't my submitted answer part work?  $.submittedSections.answers should be equivalent to $.submittedSections (as section) => section.answers.  On my way home now, will test and confirm answer tomoz :)